# How to expand a Multiindex while incrementing the data inserted?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(0, 30).reshape(-1, 5), 
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["a"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["e", "g"]]),
    columns= ["class", "type", "id", "name", "date"]
)

       class  type  id  name  date
a b e      0     1   2     3     4
    g      5     6   7     8     9
  c e     10    11  12    13    14
    g     15    16  17    18    19
  d e     20    21  22    23    24
    g     25    26  27    28    29
```

And I want to get this one by inserting the `f` between `e` and `g` with incremented numbers.

```
       class  type  id  name  date
a b e      0     1   2     3     4
    f      0     0   0     0     0
    g      5     6   7     8     9
  c e     10    11  12    13    14
    f      1     1   1     1     1
    g     15    16  17    18    19
  d e     20    21  22    23    24
    f      2     2   2     2     2
    g     25    26  27    28    29
```

I tried doing it with a loop but I failed :

```
for i in range(3):
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([[i]*5], index=pd.Index([("a", "b", "f")]), columns=df.columns)])
    
df = df.sort_index(level=2)
```

This got me :

```
       class  type  id  name  date
a b e      0     1   2     3     4
  c e     10    11  12    13    14
  d e     20    21  22    23    24
  b f      0     0   0     0     0
    f      1     1   1     1     1
    f      2     2   2     2     2
    g      5     6   7     8     9
  c g     15    16  17    18    19
  d g     25    26  27    28    29
```

Comment: Well, you'd need to insert `['a','b','f']` and `['a','c','f']` and `['a','d','f']`, which you're not doing.  And you don't want to sort by level 2.  You want the natural ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close.  You were inserting ['a','b','f'] each time, instead of varying the second element.  And you need to do the natural order sorting, not by a specific level.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(0, 30).reshape(-1, 5), 
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["a"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["e", "g"]]),
    columns= ["class", "type", "id", "name", "date"]
)

print(df)

for i in range(3):
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([[i]*5], index=pd.Index([("a", "bcd"[i], "f")]), columns=df.columns)])
    
df = df.sort_index()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       class  type  id  name  date
a b e      0     1   2     3     4
    g      5     6   7     8     9
  c e     10    11  12    13    14
    g     15    16  17    18    19
  d e     20    21  22    23    24
    g     25    26  27    28    29
       class  type  id  name  date
a b e      0     1   2     3     4
    f      0     0   0     0     0
    g      5     6   7     8     9
  c e     10    11  12    13    14
    f      1     1   1     1     1
    g     15    16  17    18    19
  d e     20    21  22    23    24
    f      2     2   2     2     2
    g     25    26  27    28    29
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
from itertools import count


def fn(x, c=count()):
    x.loc[(df.index[0][0], df.index[0][1], "f"), :] = next(c)
    return x.sort_index(level=2)


df = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(fn).droplevel([2, 3])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       class  type    id  name  date
a b e    0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
    f    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
    g    5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
  c e   10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0
    f    1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
    g   15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0
  d e   20.0  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0
    f    2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
    g   25.0  26.0  27.0  28.0  29.0
```